# Creating a function in Javascript OOP

Tags: javascript, oop

Converting function list into order so it is OOP. 
Currently I've a class shoppingCart functionality.
Inside shoppingCart we have; save, load, remove, etc and than access it.

a) Is this written in OOP correctly
b) How do you access specific functions.

**JS**

```
var cart = [];

function shoppingCart() {
  //var Item = function(title, description, price, image_url, count) { 
  this.newitem = function(title, description, price, image_url, count) {
      this.title = title
      this.description = description
      this.price = price
      this.image_url = image_url
      this.count = count
    }
    //function addIteamToCart(title, description, price,image_url, count){
  this.addNewitem = function addIteamToCart(title, description, price, image_url, count) {
    for (var i in cart) {
      console.log(cart);
      if (cart[i].title === title) {
        cart[i].count += count;
        return;
      }
    }
    var item = new Item(title, description, price, image_url, count);
    console.log(item);
    cart.push(item);
    saveCart();
  }
};



console.log(shoppingCart.newitem(sss,ddd,zzz,sss));
```

Comment: Your `Item` constructor should be outside of the `shoppingCart` constructor. Never nest classes in JS!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `ShoppingCart` object:

```
var sc = new shoppingCart();
sc.newitem(sss, ddd, zzz, sss);
console.log(sc);
```

BTW, the `cart` variable should probably be local to the `shoppingCart` function, not a global variable. And then it should be passed as an argument to `saveCart()`.

Comment: I fear OP actually meant to do `new sc.Item(…)`, which would be quite an antipattern. Can you lead him on the right path?

Comment: Thanks Bergi and Barmar

Comment: @Bergi , it should be sc.newitem('sss', 'ddd', 'zzz', 'sss');

Comment: @ChrisTarasovs `sss` seems like a strange value for `count`.

Comment: actually , we got 5 items, so  it  should be something like this sc.newitem( 'milk', 'not good for you',  40, false, 1);

Comment: Yeah. In any case, I took those to be just placeholders, not the actual values or variables to be used.